# PostgreSQL UPDATE successfully executed but stopped making changes

Tags: postgresql, update, psql

I made some UPDATE-s to my PostgreSQL DB, and after some point, they all of a sudden stopped making changes, even though the result says that there were updates made. I tried doing it inside transaction and committing it as well, but with no difference.

```
# UPDATE foo SET my_bool = false WHERE token_id = 6;
UPDATE 1
# SELECT my_bool from foo where token_id = 6;
-[ RECORD 1 ]--
is_revealed | t
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way this can happen in PostgreSQL is if there is a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger `FOR EACH ROW` that returns NULL (cancels the operation) or changes the column back to the old value.